# TYPO3: tx_news add system category selection to a link

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I'd need custom buttons (with image) for the various categories, and I'm trying to figure out if I can add the selection to the link for a header or in the RTE with the wizard.

So I link to the list page that should display only the entries tagged with the specific system category that was clicked, like with a category-menu directly as plugin -> category menu

Answer (score 0):

In **TYPO3 8** the linkHandler configuration has been improved alot. It allows you to define your own tabs in the link wizards for selecting any records. You may use this function to sys_categories inside the linkwizard and then configure the url to make it work with tx_news.
Check out the new feature here: https://usetypo3.com/linkhandler.html

**EDIT:** I guess this feature was already available in TYPO3 7 LTS but I'm not sure its not inside the documentation... not even in the docs of 8 LTS...